# MySQL server will not start from the teminal using 'mysqld' after update

Tags: mysql, bash, macos, terminal, server

After a recent system update I am having an issue getting the MySQL development server to start up using the 'mysqld' command from the terminal. I receive the error "[ERROR] InnoDB: Unable to lock ./ibdata1 error: 35"

I originally installed MySQL with brew, so I thought it might be a simple issue with the path but I've double checked and mysql is pointed at the /usr/local installation. I also checked for blocking by other running instances using htop, but found nothing.

Everything I've found online for the error seems to date back to Snow Leopard or involves using the wrong command (I checked the docs) Not even sure where to start looking for the issue based on available info.

System config:
Mac OSX 10.11.5 ElCapitan
MySQL version 5.7.11
Bash 4.3

This is my my.cnf file:

```
[client]
user                           = *my username*
password                       = *my password (file read permission set to 700)
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/mysql/mysql.sock

[mysqld]
port                           = 3306
socket                         = /var/mysql/mysql.sock
# basedir                      = /usr
# datadir                      = /var/lib/mysql
skip-external-locking
key_buffer_size = 16M
max_allowed_packet = 1M
table_open_cache = 64
sort_buffer_size = 512K
net_buffer_length = 8K
read_buffer_size = 256K
read_rnd_buffer_size = 512K
myisam_sort_buffer_size = 8M

[mysqldump]
quick
max_allowed_packet = 16M

[mysql]
no-auto-rehash
```

Anyone have any suggestions?

Comment: You probably forgot to run [`mysql_upgrade`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/mysql-upgrade.html). Look for errors in the mysqld log.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well...I feel silly now.

Using the 'mysqladmin' command I was able to determine the default order in which config files are read on my machine:

```
Default options are read from the following files in the given order:
/etc/my.cnf /etc/mysql/my.cnf /usr/local/etc/my.cnf ~/.my.cnf
```

My my.cnf file wasn't living at any of those locations, so after moving it to the '/etc/' folder I tried starting the server and it started right up.